# How to adjust the text within table

Tags: line-breaking

I am creating a table with long text separable by comma; I have defined the text width for 2nd column as 11 cm. Now, I want to present the text in the aligned form, but it does not result as expected. I also used tabulary package, but it did not help.

How can I align the text?

```
\begin{table*}
  \centering
   \caption{Website which spreads Fake News}
  \begin{tabular}{ p{1.4 cm} p{11 cm}} 
\toprule

\textbf{Language} & \textbf{Domain of Websites}   \\ \hline


English & \href{www.rt.com}{rt.com},\href{www.dailyallegiant.com}{dailyallegiant.com},\href{www.naturalnews.com}{naturalnews.com}, \href{www.thegatewaypundit.com{thegatewaypundit.com},\href{www.rt.com{rt.com},\href{www.dailyallegiant.com{dailyallegiant.com},\href{www.naturalnews.com}{naturalnews.com}, \href{www.thegatewaypundit.com}{thegatewaypundit.com},\href{www.rt.com{rt.com},\href{www.thegatewaypundit.com{thegatewaypundit.com},\href{www.rt.com{rt.com},\href{www.thegatewaypundit.com}{thegatewaypundit.com},\href{www.rt.com}{rt.com}

\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:example}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: why do you only have space after some of the commas? line breaking happens at spaces.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, I fixed it; there is no space. You are right, with space it creates line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want to have, because using your code (with some little improvements) I have this result:

[image: table preview]

The thing, as David Carlisle says, is that you have spaces only in some places.

The code that I use was this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{stack tex table}
\author{Table}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table*}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Website which spreads Fake News}
  \begin{tabular}{ p{1.4 cm} p{11 cm}} 

\textbf{Language} & \textbf{Domain of Websites}   \\ \hline


English & \href{www.rt.com}{rt.com}, \href{www.dailyallegiant.com}{dailyallegiant.com}, \href{www.naturalnews.com}{naturalnews.com}, \href{www.thegatewaypundit.com}{thegatewaypundit.com}, \href{www.rt.com}{rt.com}, \href{www.dailyallegiant.com} {dailyallegiant.com}, \href{www.naturalnews.com}{naturalnews.com},  \href{www.thegatewaypundit.com}{thegatewaypundit.com}, \href{www.rt.com}{rt.com}, \href{www.thegatewaypundit.com}{thegatewaypundit.com}, \href{www.rt.com}{rt.com}, \href{www.thegatewaypundit.com}{thegatewaypundit.com}, \href{www.rt.com}{rt.com} \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:example}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, it works; by adding [ht] and a comma between two URLs, even without additional packages,